# Update records with conditions on columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I want to update the records `name,appid` in the `table1` with matching `id`. Below statement will update the table1 values with below statement

```
update table1 set name=@name,appid=@appid where id=@id
```

I want one more condition. Update all the records for this `id`,but `appid` should not update if `(@appid is null or id=54)`. How can i make restriction(condition) on one column(`appid`). Or should i have to write another update statement? I can format the above query. Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update table1 set
    name = @name,
    appid = (case when @appid is null or id=54 then appid else @appid end)
where id=@id
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help you?

```
update
  table1 
set name=@name,
  appid=ISNUL(@appid, appid) 
where 
  id=(CASE WHEN @id=54 THEN id+1 ELSE @id END)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
update table1 set name=@name,
appid= Case when id=54 then appid else Coalesce(@appid,appid) end where id=@id
```